# Delete all space but one between last string and colon using sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have data in below format .

```
pid                           : BP
itmi                          : 40
stsus                         : NO
ltm                           : Ha Pr
```

I am trying to delete all spaces except one between last character and colon.

```
 pid : BP
 itmi : 40
 stsus : NO
 ltm : Ha Pr
```

Now if I trying to delete space using sed it is deleting all spaces irrespective of position.

Any help on same.

Comment: The title implies that line #1 should become `pid: BP`.  ("*BP*" being the *last* string on that line.)  Which is correct: the title or the message body?

Comment: So you want to add a space to the start of each line like in your posted output, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This short awk one-liner should work for your example:

```
awk '$1=$1' file
```

Test:

```
kent$  cat f
pid                           : BP
itmi                          : 40
stsus                         : NO
ltm                           : Ha Pr

kent$  awk '$1=$1' f
pid : BP
itmi : 40
stsus : NO
ltm : Ha Pr
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
<infile tr -s '[[:blank:]]'
```

Comment: This always truncates fixed spaces .. I am trying to delete all space but one from last between last string and colon

Answer (score 0):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/  +/ /g' file

pid : BP
itmi : 40
stsus : NO
ltm : Ha Pr
```

you might be better of with `tr` though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the title "*Delete all space but one one between last string and colon*" is the actual task, (and not what's shown in the sample output and message body, which leaves a space *before* the `:`), try this `sed` code:

```
sed 's/  *//' datafile
```

Output:

```
pid: BP
itmi: 40
stsus: NO
ltm: Ha Pr
```

Comment: Spaces *after* the `:` are left alone, so `Ha Pr` doesn't  become `HaPr`.

Comment: "all but one" would leave one space before the colon.

Comment: @glennjackman, Re "*before*":  it might be "*after*", since the preposition "*between*", (unlike say, "*from*"), does not specify order.